# Parcheesi- is 4-4 an 8 if I move one pawn or two 4s?

Tags: parcheesi

If I roll a double 4 (let’s assume I’m not in Doublets bonus land), and there’s a pawn of another player on a safety space four spaces in front of me, but the space 8 spaces in front is open, may I move my pawn the full 8, or must it be treated as a four and a four, and I therefore cannot move that pawn?

Rules say that if you roll a 4 and a 3, you can mover one pawn EITHER 4+3 Or 3+4.  Why would they say that instead of just saying 7?

Comment: Seems like you've answered this yourself.

Comment: I don’t think theater paragraph answers the question. It’s unclear if “move 4+3” is intended to have the same effect as “move 7” or not… it might be the same but it also could mean “move 4 and then move 3”.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple published versions of Parcheesi and thus multiple wordings of rules, but [this rulebook](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/Parcheesi.pdf) makes it clear that yes; you could move a single pawn 8 spaces on a roll of 4 and 4, even if the space 4 ahead is not free:

> You may move one or two pawns on your turn. For example, if you roll 4 + 3 **you can move one pawn 7 spaces**; or you can move one pawn 4 spaces and another pawn 3 spaces.

Comment: Any feedback on why this was downvoted?